# how to tell when script added by document.createElement('script') is loaded

Tags: javascript

I'm loading a script after page load based on a condition like so:

```
function isScriptAlreadyIncluded(src){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){
        if(scripts[i].getAttribute('src') === src) return true;
    else return false;
    }
}
if(isScriptAlreadyIncluded('contextualConversation.js')) contextualReplace();
else{
    var cCScript = document.createElement('script');
cCScript.src = 'contextualConversation.js';
    contextualReplace();
}
```

My issue is that the `contextualReplace()` in the else is being executed before the script has loaded, I believe. So how can I tell it to run that function once the script I have just added has finished loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for IE before version 9, scripts fire an event onload-

```
else{
    var cCScript = document.createElement('script');
    cCScript.onload=contextualReplace;
    cCScript.src = 'contextualConversation.js';
}
```

(To cover older IE you can use its readystatechange event, check the microsoft developer network)

Comment: Still working to this day

Answer (score 0):

You may possibly try this:

**html file**

```
<script>
  function onScriptLoad()
  {
    alert('script loaded');
  }
  //your logic to append script tag
</script>
```

**js file to load**

```
//your other script
(function()
{
   onScriptLoad(); //<-- invoke here
})();
```